# Is there a REST api endpoint for managing Google API's OAuth 2.0 client IDs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, service-accounts

I'm setting up a web application where it is possible to sign-in with a google account, as described in [Google's sign in guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

In the APIs console under "Credentials" I configured correctly my "Authorized JavaScript origins", and it is working.

However, my webapp has several (sometimes dynamic) domains, and I want to configure the "Authorized JavaScript origins" programmatically, and not manually via the APIs console interface.

Maybe it's possible to configure a service account to manage/config the details of "Client ID for Web application
" via REST api?
Though I couldn't find anything about it in the docs or references